# When, if ever, is it in keeping with the spirit of the game for an evil to confess to being evil?

Tags: werewolv.es

Sometimes, e.g., a player accused of being a wolf will admit, "Okay, you got me" rather than denying it.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean an outright confession, and not making a deliberate "mistake", allowing other scum to bus you?

Comment: I've answered the question but it probably falls under the banner of "subjective" unless you want an official moderator ruling on evil confessions being against/within site rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In multi faction games, it has been known for evil, when exposed or otherwise on the ropes to 'come clean' as it were and to divulge information they have about rival evil faction(s), in an attempt to convince the village that the other faction is a larger threat. More often than not, the confessing player is usually economical with the truth about the state of their own faction. There are numerous examples of this happening, and the successful attempts usually involve half truths and misdirects within the confession - what is the world coming to when you can't even trust an evil player to tell the complete truth?

Largely, most players dislike this approach and other kingmaker style situations, although I personally can't really blame players for trying everything they can to try to win the game (within the rules and spirit of the game).

Answer (score 2):

It's never really "okay" to confess as an evil. The most fringe scenario that I can think of would be a very long and straining game on the players and the last evil is practically caught in a situation where they don't think they can survive the rest of the days, is when I consider it remotely "okay". Then again, I'm very, VERY, against the whole idea of confession while certain other players can capitalise on confessions to survive longer by pointing the finger on other potential evils who might pose a bigger threat to villagers.